# HAML - disable back button in browser

Tags: haml

i want to stop back button action in browser

Can anyone help how to disable back button in browser using HAML(not HTML)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
%html{lang: 'en'}
  %head
    :javascript
      window.history.forward();
      function noBack() { 
        window.history.forward();
      }
  %body.login-page{:onload => "noBack();", :onpageshow => "if (event.persisted) noBack();", :onunload => ""}
```